# App in Android Studio - XML Layout doesn't appear

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a problem after updating Android Studio version from **2.2.*** to **3.0.1**. The problem is `XML Layout` doesn't show in design mode.

API / Device changing didn't solve my problem.

The error message is:
**Exception raised during rendering: android/text/TextUtils**

[image]

Details:

> java.lang.ClassFormatError: android/text/TextUtils    at
>   android.content.res.Configuration.setLayoutDirection(Configuration.java:1779)
>     at
>   android.content.res.Configuration.setLocales(Configuration.java:1725)
>     at
>   android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.calcConfigChanges(ResourcesImpl.java:484)
>     at
>   android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.updateConfiguration(ResourcesImpl.java:365)
>     at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.(ResourcesImpl.java:161)
>     at
>   android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.initSystem(Resources_Delegate.java:90)
>     at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext.initResources(BridgeContext.java:255)
>     at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderAction.setUp(RenderAction.java:242)
>     at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderAction.init(RenderAction.java:134)
>     at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.init(RenderSessionImpl.java:165)
>     at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:382)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:547)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$3(RenderTask.java:681)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Even if I create clean xml layout, I still get the same error message.
XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

Does anyone face this problem before and what is the solution for this?

**Update.** I did downgrade to 2.2.2 and everything work now. Thanks for suggesting.

Comment: did you try to refresh it.. or rebuild the project ?

Comment: @SRBbans yes, i did refresh and rebuild but it didnt solve the problem

Comment: Could you put your xml file?

Comment: i suggest you to hit clear cache and restart android studio

Comment: better put your xml also.

Answer (score 1):

Try below trick:

In Android Studio:

```
Files -> Invalidate Caches / Restart
```

Please let me know if this solved your issue.

Comment: No, it didn't solve the issue. Even if I create a new project with some completed activity the problem still remains.

Comment: @phen0men I did some research on this, but everywhere the same solution is there. To change the API level.

Answer (score 1):

Once i had this issue, and my issue was resolved when i tried changing theme in `xml layout`. 
Also check your theme in `android manifest` and `styles`. It can be an theme error.

I am attaching an image for your convenience.

[image: Press on this theme icon and change try other themes.]